# Is making changes in adb_usb.ini the same as editing 51-android.rules?

Tags: android

I notice that there are situations where you need to add some vendor ID and product ID in the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules. The line to be added for example is such as:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", ATTR{idProduct}=="9025", MODE="0666”, OWNER=""

Similarly, editing ~/.android/adb_usb.ini by just adding the following line works:
0x05c6; 0x9025

Are these instructions doing the same thing? Also, when we run the command:
android update adb

the adb_usb.ini is generated freshly and the previously made changes are overwritten.

What exactly is ~/.android/adb_usb.ini for?

Answer (score 3):

Apkudo created an adb_usb.ini containing every known Android vendor id (plus every other USB vendor on the planet). Here's how to do it:

To clone into your .android directory (for easy updating via git):

```
$ cd ~/.android
$ rm adb_usb.ini
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:apkudo/adbusbini.git
$ git pull origin master
```

Alternatively, to just copy the latest file directly into your .android:

```
$ curl -L http://raw.github.com/apkudo/adbusbini/master/adb_usb.ini \
 --O ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

A parseable listing, in case you have other uses for the data, is included in VENDORS, using the following format:

There's a blog about it here: http://blog.apkudo.com/2012/08/21/one-true-adb_usb-ini-to-rule-them-all/

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not the same: udev rules are for, well, udev, and their purpose is to make sure you get permissions to read and write the device that is created when you plug in your phone. adb_usb.ini is a configuration file for adb, but I am not sure what exactly it does. Maybe adb is changing permission on the fly or doing it's own access management, but it would have to run as root to do that. If this is documented somewhere would be interesting to know. Other than that, check adb code. EDIT: apparently it builds an array of supported vendors based on the file's contents. So if you wanted to add a vendor that adb doesn't know about, you would have to add it to the ini file.

Answer (score 1):

- `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` is for udev.
- `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` is for adb.